# Excel Multiple IF AND range statements with different outcomes

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I am struggling with an excel formula with multiple `IF AND` statements with different outcomes.

I am trying to achieve the following, if range of cell 1 and 2 is less than or equal to cell 3 then result, or if cell cell 4 and 5 is less than or equal to cell 6 then result, or if cell 7 and 8 is less than or equal to cell 9 then result

Here is what I have so far:

```
=IF(OR(AND($C$38<=DQ4,$D$38>=DQ4),"A",""),IF(AND($C$39<=DQ4,$D$39>=DQ4),"B",""))
```

Comment: It might be easier just to share some sample data and the expected outcome. I think i know what you're looking for, but just to confirm.

Comment: I neither understand `… if cell cell 4 and 5 is…` (extraneous `cell`?) nor `then result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would nest the IFs, putting the next in the FALSE of the first:

```
=IF(AND($C$38<=DQ4,$D$38>=DQ4),"A",IF(AND($C$39<=DQ4,$D$39>=DQ4),"B",""))
```

continuing in this vain with other choices.

But my guess is that a simple VLOOKUP will work:

```
=VLOOKUP(DQ4,$C$38:$E$45,3,FALSE)
```

Where column E has the desired output.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the rapid response. Works perfectly!

Comment: @JosephKappel: when an answer indeed solves your question, it's a good habit to accept the answer, so other people know that there's no need to look further.